# Invalid int encoding on deserializing kafka avro topics in spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, byte, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to process streaming avro data from kafka using spark structured streaming (version-2.3.1), so i tried with [this](https://github.com/Neuw84/spark-continuous-streaming/blob/master/src/main/java/es/aconde/structured/StructuredDemo.java) example to de-serialize.
It works only if the topics `value` part contains `StringType`, but in my case the schema contains `long and integers` like below:

```
public static final String USER_SCHEMA = "{"
        + "\"type\":\"record\","
        + "\"name\":\"variables\","
        + "\"fields\":["
        + "  { \"name\":\"time\", \"type\":\"long\" },"
        + "  { \"name\":\"thnigId\", \"type\":\"string\" },"
        + "  { \"name\":\"controller\", \"type\":\"int\" },"
        + "  { \"name\":\"module\", \"type\":\"int\" }"
        + "]}";
```

So it gives an exception at

```
sparkSession.udf().register("deserialize", (byte[] data) -> {
GenericRecord record = recordInjection.invert(data).get(); //throws error at invert method.
return RowFactory.create(record.get("time"), record.get("thingId").toString(), record.get("controller"), record.get("module"));
    }, DataTypes.createStructType(type.fields()));
```

saying

```
Failed to invert: [B@22a45e7
Caused by java.io.IOException: Invalid int encoding.
```

because I'm having `time, controller and module` in schema `long and int` types.

I guess this is some sort of encoding and decoding formats errors of byte array `byte[] data`.

Answer (score 2):

Did you take a look at this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1650. It talks specifically about the issue you might be running into. The default UTF-8 encoding can result in loss during the encoding/decoding process.

I would also suggest if you are dealing with binary encoded data to use [Base64](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) encoding to save/transmit the data as that utilizes ISO-8859-1 which is the right encoding the use per the link above.

Comment: the issue was I tried to de-serialize confluent avro which has meta data long with the avro record that's the issue.

Answer (score -1):

i also faced this case, I guess maybe you configurate your kafka value-deserializer is default String deserializer, you can try to change the deserializer to org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer.

that is my solution.

hope can help you